# When do we have $Dx^{r} = rx^{r-1}$ for $x \leq 0$?

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms

Since, if $x > 0$ then $Dx^{r} = rx^{r-1}$ for real $r$, when do we have this result for $x \leq 0$?

I think the point is to circumvent the trouble that if $x \leq 0$ then $\log x$ is meaningless, as $$Dx^{r} = D e^{r\log x} = e^{r\log x}\cdot \frac{r}{x} = rx^{r-1}.$$

Comment: How do you define $x^r$ when $x$ is negative and $r$ irrationnal?

Comment: $d f(x)$ is called the _differential_ of the function _f_, which, while it resembles the derivative is different from it. You are thus not allowed to decide that "By $df(x)$ I mean the derivative of a function _f_ at an _x_ in the domain of _f_." You should thus write the derivative $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$

Comment: @BernardMassé: Yep, thanks, I see. The symbol is for my private sketching, so I re-defined that. I am not intending to "invent" notation.

Comment: @BernardMassé: Ah never mind, I think about a convenient notation in existence, please refer to my edits if you would like to.

Comment: If x is zero is a constant function. If x is negative, you have to consider complex numbers at least and it should work for rational r. For irrational r you might need something more advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It very likely depends on precisely how you are defining $x^r$ on negative $x$ for non-integer $r$. However, we can sort of work around this while maintaining your original idea. In particular, we want to define:
$$x^r=e^{\log(x)\cdot r}$$
and the only troublesome bit in here is $\log(x)$, which isn't clearly defined for negative numbers. Let us work around this by defining:
$$x^r = e^{f(x)\cdot r}$$
where $f(x)$ is any continuous function such that $e^{f(x)}=x$. Differentiating with $x$, one determines that:
$$e^{f(x)}f'(x)=1$$
$$f'(x)=e^{-f(x)}$$
Then, if we differentiate $x^r=e^{f(x)\cdot r}$ we get:
$$e^{f(x)\cdot r}\cdot f'(x)\cdot r$$
and replacing $f'(x)$ by the identity we found for it:
$$e^{f(x)\cdot r}\cdot e^{-f(x)}\cdot r$$
or simplifying:
$$r\cdot e^{f(x)\cdot (r-1)}=r\cdot x^{r-1}$$
as desired.

Okay, this might seem a bit suspicious at first - $f$ is really just what we want to call a logarithm - and somehow, we're claiming this works for negative numbers too, even though it's basically the same as the work you did. The subtlety is that all of the above works perfectly well in the complex plane (except at $0$, which can easily be handled alone), but is not as straightforwards as you'd hope. In particular, we *can* take the logarithm of any non-zero complex number, but since $e^x$ is periodic in $2i\pi$ (see [Euler's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity)), there is no unique inverse - thus $f$ stands in for what the logarithm is doing "near $x$" - so we're saying no matter how we locally choose our inverse, the theorem works out. We could, indeed, define $\log(-x)=\log(x)+i\pi$ (for $x>0$), and do all the above directly with that definition, but the above shows that as long as our definition of $x^r$ is sensible, things will work out okay.